# How to get to use {align} with an unusual document class?

Tags: amsmath, align

So I'm required to use a particular documentclass, "llncs", which for some reason is preventing me from using {align}.  Is there an alternative that I can use?

The beginning of my tex file

```
\documentclass{llncs}
```

My tex part with errors is

```
\begin{align*}
\forall q \in S \begin{cases}
PRUNE(I_{p_j}) \iff d(p_j,q) - r \ge d_{m_j}\\
PRUNE(O_{p_j}) \iff d(p_j,q) + r < d_{m_j}
\end{cases}
\end{align*}
```

Comment: \documentclass{llncs} is the starting line

Comment: In that case, have you tried issuing the command `\RequirePackage{amsmath}` *before* the statement `\documentclass{llncs}`? I must confess I'm not familiar with the `llncs` document class. It doesn't seem to part of the TeXLive distribution.

Comment: unbelievable, that's all I needed to do !? make an answer please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the `llncs` document class, and it doesn't seem to be included in the TeXLive distribution. That said, if you can't load the `amsmath` package via a `\usepackage` statement *after* the `\documentclass` directive, the following might do the job for you:

```
\RequirePackage{amsmath}
\documentclass{llncs}
% rest of document
```